# Excel crashing when using ThisWorkbook.Save to avoid the message "click yes to save macro-free work book"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to hide alerts to avoid the message saying "click yes to save macro-free work book etc.", but Excel crashes.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim v As Variant
v = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(, "Excel files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

If VarType(v) = vbString Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=v, _
    FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
End If

ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Quit
```

After the user chooses the destination and name of the file to save, the workbook should close. To avoid the message that confirms saving I used ThisWorkbook.Save.

**EDIT**

I fixed it by using

```
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True  
Application.Quit  
Application.ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False   
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False`
```

instead of

```
ThisWorkbook.Save  
Application.Quit
```

Comment: Working on my end, even if the code looks bad. I have a guess: are `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook` supposed to be different workbooks or are they the same workbook? They can be ***vastly*** different.

Comment: They are different, `ActiveWorkbook` is the original file with the vba project. `ThisWorkbook` is the new file that was just created

Comment: Also if you have any suggested change in the code, i would appreciate that.

Comment: Kindly post your whole code, if it's alright.

Comment: it's pretty long, and believe me if you thought the code above was bad the whole program is a disaster. It's pretty sloppy and it only performs simple tasks